# Calculate normal direction in image

Tags: matlab, image-processing, derivative

I am trying to calculate normal direction within a grayscale image using pixel-neighborhood like this:

[image: method]

Suppose I have a matrix

```
|148 141 145|
|144 140 148|
|146 147 148|
```

The normal direction that I want to calculate is the maximum grayscale difference from the center pixel. if the grayscale difference is more than one value, the final normal direction of that plurality is a summation of normal direction.

How to implement that method efficiently in MATLAB?

### Edit

---

I tried to implement it, but I doubt the result is correct or not.

```
function [resVectorDirection, magnitudeNormal, actualNormal] = estSurfNorm(newImg)
% Define empty array
resVectorDirection = [];
magnitudeNormal = [];
actualNormal = [];
for i = 2:size(newImg, 1) - 1
    for j = 2:size(newImg, 2) - 1

        % Obtain value from 8-neighborhood matrix
        imgNeighborhood(1) = newImg(i-1,j-1);
        imgNeighborhood(2) = newImg(i-1,j);
        imgNeighborhood(3) = newImg(i-1,j+1);
        imgNeighborhood(4) = newImg(i,j-1);
        imgNeighborhood(5) = newImg(i,j+1);
        imgNeighborhood(6) = newImg(i+1,j-1);
        imgNeighborhood(7) = newImg(i+1,j);
        imgNeighborhood(8) = newImg(i+1,j+1);

        % Perform sort operation for array
        [value, index] = sort(imgNeighborhood, 'descend');
        % Obtain total largest value in array
        totalLargestValue = sum(ismember(imgNeighborhood, value(1)));
        % Obtain all largest value in array
        largestValue = value(1:totalLargestValue);
        % Obtain all index largest value in array
        indexLargestValue = index(1:totalLargestValue);

        % Check if there are multiple value from 8-neighborhood matrix
        if (totalLargestValue > 1)
            for k = 1:totalLargestValue
                if (indexLargestValue(k) == 1)
                    multiVectorDirection(k, 1) = (i-1) - i;
                    multiVectorDirection(k, 2) = (j-1) - j;
                elseif (indexLargestValue(k) == 2)
                    multiVectorDirection(k, 1) = (i-1) - i;
                    multiVectorDirection(k, 2) = j - j;
                elseif (indexLargestValue(k) == 3)
                    multiVectorDirection(k, 1) = (i-1) - i;
                    multiVectorDirection(k, 2) = (j+1) - j;
                elseif (indexLargestValue(k) == 4)
                    multiVectorDirection(k, 1) = i - i;
                    multiVectorDirection(k, 2) = (j-1) - j;
                elseif (indexLargestValue(k) == 5)
                    multiVectorDirection(k, 1) = i - i;
                    multiVectorDirection(k, 2) = (j+1) - j;
                elseif (indexLargestValue(k) == 6)
                    multiVectorDirection(k, 1) = (i+1) - i;
                    multiVectorDirection(k, 2) = (j-1) - j;
                elseif (indexLargestValue(k) == 7)
                    multiVectorDirection(k, 1) = (i+1) - i;
                    multiVectorDirection(k, 2) = j - j;
                elseif (indexLargestValue(k) == 8)
                    multiVectorDirection(k, 1) = (i+1) - i;
                    multiVectorDirection(k, 2) = (j+1) - j;
                end
            end
            % Calculate suface normal direction and magnitude for multiple
            % direction
            tempVectorDirection = sum(multiVectorDirection, 1);
            resVectorDirection = [resVectorDirection; tempVectorDirection];
            actualNormal = [actualNormal; i j tempVectorDirection(1)+i tempVectorDirection(2)+j];
            magnitudeNormal = [magnitudeNormal; largestValue(1)];
        elseif (totalLargestValue == 1)
            if (indexLargestValue == 1)
                singleVectorDirection(1) = (i-1) - i;
                singleVectorDirection(2) = (j-1) - j;
            elseif (indexLargestValue == 2)
                singleVectorDirection(1) = (i-1) - i;
                singleVectorDirection(2) = j - j;
            elseif (indexLargestValue == 3)
                singleVectorDirection(1) = (i-1) - i;
                singleVectorDirection(2) = (j+1) - j;
            elseif (indexLargestValue == 4)
                singleVectorDirection(1) = i - i;
                singleVectorDirection(2) = (j-1) - j;
            elseif (indexLargestValue == 5)
                singleVectorDirection(1) = i - i;
                singleVectorDirection(2) = (j+1) - j;
            elseif (indexLargestValue == 6)
                singleVectorDirection(1) = (i+1) - i;
                singleVectorDirection(2) = (j-1) - j;
            elseif (indexLargestValue == 7)
                singleVectorDirection(1) = (i+1) - i;
                singleVectorDirection(2) = j - j;
            elseif (indexLargestValue == 8)
                singleVectorDirection(1) = (i+1) - i;
                singleVectorDirection(2) = (j+1) - j;
            end
            % If surface direction is only one direction, then assign it to
            % actual surface normal and magnitude
            resVectorDirection = [resVectorDirection; singleVectorDirection];
            actualNormal = [actualNormal; i j singleVectorDirection(1)+i singleVectorDirection(2)+j];
            magnitudeNormal = [magnitudeNormal; largestValue];
        end
    end
end

end
```

Comment: You say you want to calculate the grayscale difference, but your image shows the direction of the **maximum** grayscale difference. Have you implemented your calculation, even if inefficiently? Where were the bottlenecks. What have you tried in order to speed it up? Where, exactly, are areas you think can be improved upon? What has your research turned up?

Comment: That is the weirdest way of computing a gradient I’ve ever seen. Why not do it the normal way, combining partial derivatives along each of the axes?

Comment: Yes, I mean the grayscale difference is in maximum value. I tried to implement it, but I doubt the result is correct or not. I attach my code in my question. If you don't mind, you can review my code.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I just follow the method from the actual research paper. I don't know if I use another method besides that like partial derivatives it will get the same result with the author did in that research paper.

Comment: It looks like this is a very rough approximation, likely they’re concerned about speed and not about precision or correctness. I find such optimizations highly uninteresting... :) — Also, computing an actual gradient is likely faster than your implementation!

Comment: I'm not sure what output you're expecting from your function. How are you representing your direction? What is `actualNormal`? Can you give us a *small* example of what you're looking for?

Comment: @beaker I'm still confused with the output value of that method. So, I assume that output value is pixel coordinate from the center neighborhood to normal point. I represent the direction with vector direction, the tail of direction is pixel coordinate of the center neighborhood and the head is pixel coordinate where belongs to the maximum grayscale difference.